# Multiple chrome instances with one user (remote VM)

Tags: linux, debian, chrome, rdp

I want multiple people to remotely log in on a VM with the same user and use 'individual' Chrome instances. (they don't have access to chrome on their devices)

So far I've tried multiple solutions:

- Windows Server -> needed licenses for more than 2 sessions
- Linux Server -> multiple sessions with 1 users works but can't run multiple sessions of Chrome simultaneously

Is there a way to run multiple Chrome sessions simultaneously on Linux ? Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by *'individual' Chrome instances.* How *individual* should that be? Anyhow, there is an option to have **Chromium** run multiple independent instances with the `--temp-profile` parameter, which might help you. The description from `man` is this:

> Use a throw-away/temporary profile for this session.  This creates an
>   entirely new user profile temporarily. It is not the same as incognito
>   mode.

You can easily find more info on this topic with Internet searches. Do your test in the extend needed.

Comment: When I start multiple RDP sessions, it opens a new tab in Chrome every time on the first RDP connection. I want each RDP session to have it's individual Chrome screen

Comment: @Nicolas1994 Have you tested from a terminal with the parameter in my answer? It opens new windows on my Debian.

Comment: I've set this (in /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop)  "Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --temp-profile %U" but doesn't seem to do much ? I'm not a linux expert so if u could explain more that would be helpful

Comment: @Nicolas1994 I'm not sure how the desktop icon is supposed to be defined. Another thing is that I've Chromium not Chrome, and they may differ. Chromium is present in the standard Debian repository. You have to check `man chrome` or similar for the option exact wording. Or try installing and using Chromium, which should be the same as mine. As for the desktop shortcut again, I'd suggest you first test from a terminal - that's how I'd do this, though it might make little difference.

Comment: I set up chromium to start on boot with the --temp-profile but it still opens a new tab on new sessions